# JMeter Firefox Driver Config unable to launch browser

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am attempting to use JMeter's FireFox Driver config so that I can use a Web Driver Sampler to wait for a page to process an internal, automated OAuth process that redirects the page, but I am running into an issue with JMeter loading Firefox.

The only error that prints for it is `Failed to connect binary FirefoxBinary` but there is zero additional information that I understand.

What additional steps do I need to take that literally every single tutorial on how to use Firefox Driver Config in JMeter seems to not tell you?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows: 
":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["fa"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (or)","description":"ୱିକିପିଡ଼ିଆ  (ଓଡ଼ିଆ)","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["or"]},{"name":"വിക്കിപീഡിയ (ml)","description":"വിക്കിപീഡിയ, സ്വതന്ത്ര സര്‍വ്വവിജ്ഞാനകോശം ","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ml"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (ia)","description":"Wikipedia, le encyclopedia libere","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ia"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (ms)","description":"Wikipedia, ensiklopedia bebas","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ms"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (no)","description":"Wikipedia, den frie encyklopedi","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["NO"]},{"name":"Википедия (ru)","description":"Википедия, свободная энциклопедия","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ru"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (br)","description":"Wikipedia, an holloueziadur digor","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["br"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (pl)","description":"Wikipedia, wolna encyklopedia","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["pl"]},{"name":"ວິກິພີເດຍ (lo)","description":"ວິກິພີເດຍ, ສາລານຸກົມເສລີ","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["lo"]},{"name":"Wikipedija (sl)","description":"Wikipedija, prosta enciklopedija","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["sl"]},{"name":"Vikipēdija","description":"Vikipēdija, brīvā enciklopēdija","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["lv"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (sv)","description":"Wikipedia, den fria encyklopedin","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["sv-SE"]},{"name":"Вікіпэдыя (be-tarask)","description":"Вікіпэдыя, вольная энцыкляпэдыя","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["be-tarask"]},{"name":"Biquipedia (an)","description":"A enciclopedia Libre","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["an"]}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":null,"maxVersion":null}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"incognito":"spanning","userPermissions":{"permissions":[],"origins":[]},"icons":{"16":"favicon.ico"},"iconURL":null,"blocklistState":0,"blocklistURL":null,"startupData":null,"hidden":true,"installTelemetryInfo":null,"recommendationState":null,"rootURI":"resource://search-extensions/wikipedia/","location":"app-builtin"}
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from resource://search-extensions/wikipedia/
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on wikipedia@search.mozilla.org version 1.0
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on wikipedia@search.mozilla.org version 1.0
1565650395862   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/68.0.1/20190717172542/Darwin_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/release/Darwin%2018.7.0/default/default/update.xml
1565650395943   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1565650396315   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1565650396318   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/3s/qk2pg7q16m5056kjfvgkqk4c0000gn/T/tmpaddon-f9b30e
1565650396811   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1565650396814   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/3s/qk2pg7q16m5056kjfvgkqk4c0000gn/T/tmpaddon-26509c

Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'Tanner-Devetry-Mac.local', ip: '192.168.231.124', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:125) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:100) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:21) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:995) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["fa"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (or)","description":"ୱିକିପିଡ଼ିଆ  (ଓଡ଼ିଆ)","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["or"]},{"name":"വിക്കിപീഡിയ (ml)","description":"വിക്കിപീഡിയ, സ്വതന്ത്ര സര്‍വ്വവിജ്ഞാനകോശം ","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ml"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (ia)","description":"Wikipedia, le encyclopedia libere","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ia"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (ms)","description":"Wikipedia, ensiklopedia bebas","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ms"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (no)","description":"Wikipedia, den frie encyklopedi","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["NO"]},{"name":"Википедия (ru)","description":"Википедия, свободная энциклопедия","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["ru"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (br)","description":"Wikipedia, an holloueziadur digor","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["br"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (pl)","description":"Wikipedia, wolna encyklopedia","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["pl"]},{"name":"ວິກິພີເດຍ (lo)","description":"ວິກິພີເດຍ, ສາລານຸກົມເສລີ","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["lo"]},{"name":"Wikipedija (sl)","description":"Wikipedija, prosta enciklopedija","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["sl"]},{"name":"Vikipēdija","description":"Vikipēdija, brīvā enciklopēdija","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["lv"]},{"name":"Wikipedia (sv)","description":"Wikipedia, den fria encyklopedin","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["sv-SE"]},{"name":"Вікіпэдыя (be-tarask)","description":"Вікіпэдыя, вольная энцыкляпэдыя","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["be-tarask"]},{"name":"Biquipedia (an)","description":"A enciclopedia Libre","creator":null,"developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null,"locales":["an"]}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":null,"maxVersion":null}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"incognito":"spanning","userPermissions":{"permissions":[],"origins":[]},"icons":{"16":"favicon.ico"},"iconURL":null,"blocklistState":0,"blocklistURL":null,"startupData":null,"hidden":true,"installTelemetryInfo":null,"recommendationState":null,"rootURI":"resource://search-extensions/wikipedia/","location":"app-builtin"}
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from resource://search-extensions/wikipedia/
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on wikipedia@search.mozilla.org version 1.0
1565650376116   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on wikipedia@search.mozilla.org version 1.0
1565650395862   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/68.0.1/20190717172542/Darwin_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/release/Darwin%2018.7.0/default/default/update.xml
1565650395943   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1565650396315   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1565650396318   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/3s/qk2pg7q16m5056kjfvgkqk4c0000gn/T/tmpaddon-f9b30e
1565650396811   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1565650396814   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/3s/qk2pg7q16m5056kjfvgkqk4c0000gn/T/tmpaddon-26509c

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]
    ... 16 more
2019-08-12 16:53:41,118 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'jp@gc - Web Driver Sampler - Perform OAuth'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:52) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
2019-08-12 16:53:42,339 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: ThreadGroup 1-1
2019-08-12 16:53:42,339 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: ThreadGroup 1-1
2019-08-12 16:53:42,339 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-08-12 16:53:42,339 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

**UPDATE**

I went ahead and tried to use Firefox 26 instead, but now I am getting an even less helpful error.

Here are the details of my environment:
JMeter: `5.1.1`
Firefox: `26.0`
Selenium/WebDriver Kit: `2.52.0`

Here is the error I am getting now:

```
2019-08-13 11:52:06,427 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-08-13 11:52:06,428 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-08-13 11:52:06,432 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-08-13 11:52:06,557 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-08-13 11:52:06,558 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-08-13 11:52:06,558 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-08-13 11:52:06,558 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-08-13 11:52:06,560 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-08-13 11:52:06,560 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-08-13 11:52:06,560 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-13 11:52:06,561 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-13 11:52:06,561 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:97) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:22) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
2019-08-13 11:52:06,562 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-08-13 11:52:06,562 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

And here is the set up I followed from BlazeMeter's [tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) updated in April of 2019:

[image: Firefox Driver Config]

[image: WebDriver Sampler]

What else do I need to do to get Jmeter to run these tests??? Would be nice if there was documentation that was up to date and explained all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your output:

> Build info: version: '2.52.0',

According to [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) you can use Firefox version 46 or older with this [Selenium Firefox Driver 2.52.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver) so either consider downgrading your Firefox to [Firefox 46](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/) or upgrade to the latest version of WebDriver Sampler Plugin which is [version 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.1) as of now, this way you will be able to use modern Firefoxen via [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

You can install new JMeter Plugins and keep old ones up-to-date using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: What do you mean by `use modern firefoxen via GeckoDriver`? I haven't found a single tutorial that mentions this? I do have the version 3.1 for the WebDriver Sampler Plugin, but not sure how to go about the GeckoDriver you speak of...

Comment: I've updated my question after changing my Firefox version to 26 (JMeter's plugin web driver's repo says it's 26 not 46..). Can you help me solve it please?